# 3 columns layout with rounded corners

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns

I'm trying to make something looks like this:
http://student.santarosa.edu/~anarbuto/CSS/templates/stylin2_chapters/chapter_5/3_col_rounded.html
but without any JS or CSS hacks.

Also tried this:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/fixed-width-or-liquid-layout.htm

and many other examples, but none of them works well.

I'd like the left and the right columns to be a fix width (say 300px), and the middle column takes the rest of the page.

Not sure if anyone can help..?

Thanks!!!

Edit: They need to be of same height (without specifying the height), ie. all 3 columns should have same height as the tallest column.

Comment: That is so easy, just use `border-radius: 8px;` and you are good to go

Comment: Sorry, they difficulty I'm facing is not the round corner, but the 3 columns layout with same height (ie. holy grail example)

Answer (score 0):

To make the corners of div round you have to use css and just go to
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp
This is not a hack I believe.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

For your layout to be fluit I added % to the width:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBH3A/3/

CSS:

```
h1{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header{
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#left{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;

}

#right{
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

#center{
    background-color: red;
    width: 58%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

---

I made a quick example for a 960px grid layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/qBH3A/1/

I just set the values to a max-width and width.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <h1>header</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="left">
        <h1>Left</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <h1>right</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="center">
        <h1>center</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#container{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header{
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#left{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

#right{
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

#center{
    background-color: red;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 540px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Note that I used border-radius of 10px;

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: I think he wanted a fluid layout. I quickly adjusted some things on your fiddle to make it fluid http://jsfiddle.net/qBH3A/2/

Comment: Ah yes, but the example he provided was a fixed layout so I did not add that. thanks anyway I will add it :)

Comment: Thanks Kees and Vector! Sorry I think I didn't mention clearly, they needs to be of same height (but not fixed height). ie. all 3 columns should have same height as the tallest column.. it seems a bit difficult.. (I'm not a CSS expert..:( )